# Etoc.pdf: cannot extract the snippets?

Tags: etoc

How do I access the snippets of the [etoc.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/etoc/etoc.pdf)?
Here is how page 71 looks like on my system:
[image: Print screen]
I am on a Macbook with Ventura. 
Using "Aperçu" or "Skim", Click or Ctrl+Click has no effect.
I cannot find any "attachment" or "comment".

Comment: in adobe reader (on windows) it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(moved from comment) I confirm that on mac osx with Preview or Skim it does not work; you need Adobe Reader. I have a very old one on my mac os x (Adobe Reader 10.1.16) and it works there.  You can also go to the [source folder on CTAN](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/etoc), download `etoc.dtx` to some directory on your machine, execute <strike>`etex etoc.dtx`</strike> as per README instructions on [ctan page](https://ctan.org/pkg/etoc) and you will find all snippets files after that in that directory.

##### update

actually you need `pdflatex etoc.dtx` to extract these files, doing `etex etoc.dtx` only extracts `etoc.sty`.  I should have tried first...